# How to write a polynomial in mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Consider the polynomial $ \ x^3 - 3\ x^2 +2\ x -1$
How can this polynomial be written in mod 3 ?

What confuses me is that I thought we don't change any power . If we have to also consider the powers then will the leading coefficient be equal to zero then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is an integer, then
\begin{align*}
&x^3-3x^2+2x-1\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^3-0x^2+2x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^3+2x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x+2x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)
\qquad\text{[since $x^3\equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;3)$]}\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&3x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&0x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&2\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $x$ is just an indeterminate, then you can't replace $x^3$ by $x$, but you can replace coefficients by their residues, mod $3$, hence, with that interpretation, you can get
\begin{align*}
&x^3-3x^2+2x-1
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;\,
\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^3-0x^2+2x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^3+2x-1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&x^3+2x+2\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: actually in my note it is right up to your 4th line before "since" but I could not understand how we get x from $ \ x^3 $ although we should not change the powers

Comment: If $x$ is intended as an _indeterminate_, then you _can't_ change powers. If $x$ is just an unknown integer, then $x^3\equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;3)$ by Fermat's little Theorem, so with that interpretation, $x^3$ can be replaced by $x$. Thus, it depends on the intended interpretation of $x$. If you really meant _polynomial_, then $x$ should be regarded as an indeterminate, so in that case, you can't replace $x^3$ by $x$. In my answer, I showed both interpretations.

Answer (score 4):

> What confuses me is that I thought we don't change any power . If we have to also consider the powers then will the leading coefficient be equal to zero then.

Your first thought is correct: we don't change any power. Even though $3$ is in the exponent, we don't take the exponents mod 3, but only the coefficients.

So, taking a polynomial mod 3 just means taking each coefficient mod 3 (and leaving the exponents). For example, $6x^3 + 4x^2 - 2 \mod 3$ would be $0x^3 + x^2 + 1$, which is the same as $x^2 + 1$ since we can drop $0$s. This is because $6 \mod 3$ is $0$, $4 \mod 3$ is $1$, and $-2 \mod 3$ is $1$.